# sending file to server by okhttp

Tags: android, node.js, server, okhttp

I have this `node.js` code in my server side app:

```
app.post('/upload',function (req,resp) {
    console.log(req);
    var email=req.headers['email']
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null,'uploads/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null,"asdsad"+".jpg")
        }
    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('propic')
    upload(req, resp, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        resp.send({status:true})
    })
})
```

I want to send a bitmap in client side (Android) to server.
I used the `okhttp` library and I want to create form-data.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? We can't write your code for you. Show us your Android code and post what problems/errors you are seeing and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You must send `File` to your server instead of `bitmap` and must use `POST` method to handle the request to Server side.
and write this codes to send your file into the server:

```
public class UploadService {

    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

    public void uploadImage(File image, String imageName) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", imageName, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, image))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost:8080/v1/upload")
                .post(requestBody).build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }

    }

}
```